# Understanding Overriding Concept

Tags: java

I have two classes, `Employee` and `Department`.

`Department` is subclass of `Employee`.

The code is below:

```
public class Employee {
    public void getEmployeeDetails(String name , String age) {
        System.out.println("Employee.getEmployeeDetails()");
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Employee.print()");
    }
}

public class Department extends Employee {
    public void getEmployeeDetails(String name , int age) {
        System.out.println("Department.getEmployeeDetails()");
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Department.print()");
    }
}
```

I am running following code.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Department();
        e1.getEmployeeDetails("Manish", "10");
        e1.print();
    }
```

The output is

```
Employee.getEmployeeDetails()

Department.print()
```

When I run the `getEmployeeDetails()` method the JVM is calls the parent class, but when I call the `print()` method the JVM calls the child class.

Why is this happening this way?

Comment: If you make `Department` extend `Employee` then I'm afraid you have a fundamental misunderstanding about what inheritance means. Best go read a good book on the subject.

Comment: You should use `extends` if the subclass is a more specific case of the base class. For example, a dog is a specific case of an animal; so a class `Dog` would be a logical extension of a class `Animal`. But a Department is not a specific type of Employee; a department _contains_ employees.

Answer (score 4):

`getEmployeeDetails()` of `Department` doesn't override `getEmployeeDetails()` of `Employee`, since it has different type of arguments (one takes 2 `String`s and the other takes a `String` and an `int`). That's why `e1.getEmployeeDetails("Manish", "10");` calls the method of the base class `Employee`, which takes 2 `String`s.

On the other hand, `print()` of `Department` does override `print()` of `Employee`, since it has the same signature. Therefore `print()` of `Department` is executed.

Comment: Does that mean it overloads, or is that only applicable for methods in the same class?

Comment: @reedb89 Yes, `getEmployeeDetails()` of `Department` overloads `getEmployeeDetails()` of `Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method signatures for the `getEmployeeDetails` methods differ. Since you are supplying two strings as parameters, the superclass method is called since the `Department` class does not have a method with such a signature (it only has one with a String and int parameter).

The `print` method is correctly *Overriden* since it has the same method signature (method name, parameters and their types). Hence it is called on the `Department` class.

Answer (score 0):

Override a method should respect **signature** ,it means method name and parameters type should be the same. Note: **the type you are returning doesn't effect it**

In your child class you are not overriding the parent method .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand the overriding *concept*, as your question is titled, then you need to understand inheritance.  This example (creating an inheritance relationship between `Employee` and `Department`) does not reflect such an understanding, so really you need to take a step back.

Something like `Manager` could be a subclass of `Employee`, because every manager is an employee.

`Department` could be subclass of something like `OrgUnit` because every department is an organizational unit.

But a department is not an employee, so there is no conceptual sense to using extends in the way you've shown; so at a conceptual level, this example cannot be used to explain overriding.

To understand the *mechanism* of overriding, this example is usable.  In that context, the reason for the behavior you see is that a subclass method only overrides a superclass method if it accepts the same argument types.  What you have with `getEmployeeDetails()` is method *overloading* - two methods with the same name but incompatible argument lists

Answer (score 0):

For    getEmployeeDetails method is not getting overridden as its parameters are different.
The rule of overriding is that the method signature must be the same which is not the case here.

Also you should read about ***dynamic method dispatch*** which feature tells that at runtime it's decided which method to be called(parent or child).

For example:

1) For below it will call method of Department class as the instance is of Department class even if the instance variable is of Employee class:

```
Employee e1 = new Department();
e1.getEmployeeDetails("Manish", "10");
e1.print();
```

2) In below case it will call the method of Employee class:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee();
e1.getEmployeeDetails("Manish", "10");
e1.print();
```

Hope this clears your doubt ;)